# Swift UIView wont hide image

Tags: swift, uiview

I am displaying a custom UIView. There is a variable 'hideLogo' which when set to false should hide the Logo image when the view appears. However the logo is only hidden once the subview is re-added.

How can I make the image hidden when the view is added first time.

```
class MenuBar: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var LogoImage: UIImageView!

 static var showLogo: Bool?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        if(MenuBar.showLogo == false){
            self.LogoImage.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

subview instantiated from another class:

```
MenuBar.showLogo = false
self.view.insertSubview(messageView.create(viewController: self), belowSubview: view.viewWithTag(1)!)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting `showLogo` but you are not *responding* to that by setting the logo image's `isHidden` to `true`. And it's going to be hard for you to do that so long as `showLogo` is a `static` property. Make it an *instance* property and now you can give it a setter observer.